# Binding a writable directory in singularity

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, singularity-container

I'm trying to setup a singularity container for an image processing application, and I need it to be able to save images to a specified directory. I had originally tried using a straight `-B` flag, but that seems to mount a directory as read only if the container wasn't being run as root. Is there a way to either make a bind r/w for any user, or would I need to use some sort of scratch directory or fusemount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The write permissions for the bound directory match those on the host system. If you want anyone to be able to write to a given directory, set permissions on the host with `chmod 777 dir_name`. Keep in mind this will allow *anyone* to read, write and delete files in the directory. Consider adding users to a shared group and using group permissions (`chmod g+rwX dir_name`) if there are people using the server who should not have access.

If the directory has the right permissions but you still can't write to it when it's bound, you may want to use `singularity --debug exec ...` to see that everything is being correctly bound to the container.

Comment: That was it... I had forgotten that I the owner of the sub-directory I was trying to write to had been made as root. chown'ing it back to be owned by me fixed the issue. Thanks!